# When using CNOSDB, the database creation failed

Tags: cnosdb

I am deploying a 3+2 model. After the deployment is complete, I execute the database creation statement and the following error is prompted. However, after waiting for a while, the database creation is successful.
[image]

This is the CNOSDB version I am using.

```
cnosdb 2.4.0, revision 036ef942913d45d9345be010595f6c0b5390e2a5
```

Does anyone have any solutions?

Comment: The number of replicas is limited by the number of CnosDB cluster nodes. The error reported at the beginning means that when you execute sql, there is only one node in the cluster. But you deployed 3+2, so I guess the second node may not have been initialized when you executed it.